# Embed Excel as OLE Object in MS Word showing Error

Tags: .net, excel, ms-word, vsto, ole

I have created a **VSTO** for MS Excel and MS Word as well. I am trying to **embed OLE Object of Excel** in my word document. It works for me for New Document. Now I saved this document somewhere on my hard drive (for eg C:\ drive). Now I am trying to open that word document from File -> Open . Now when I double click on table that is Excel OLE object , it shows me Message like this... [image]
I think there is no issue in my VSTO. I have disabled both my VSTO and follow the same procedure. But failed again.
Has anyone tried doing this before successfully. Please assist me with sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround all your Application_Workbook code with try-catch-finally and release the workbook object.
eg.

```
void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb) { 
    try {
        // Do Stuff
    } catch (Exception) {
        // Probably Eat it
    } finally {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Wb);
    }
 }
```

Here is a reference ...

https://theofficecontext.com/2012/10/09/vsto-and-comole/

Comment: @BaummitAugen I made changes. Please re-assess my answer

Comment: Looks better now, thanks. (Not my downvote btw, I lack domain knowledge to vote on this answer.)

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work completely as described above. I can if I release all COM objects I have accessed from the Workbook Open handler. Unfortunately with some exceptions though. For example running through CustomDocumentProperties, if I release the Custom properties list it works. However if there are CustomDocumentProperties and I iterate through them, and try to release each DocumentProperty, it does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Its common problem you will see when you embed excel in word and is caused by addins. One solution to resolve this is in your addins (both word and excel) unhook all application and document events, like document open. Also disable any third party addin installed and check if that solves problem.

Comment: Hi Brijesh Mishra thanks for your reply. I am very much new to this. can u please tell me how to unhook all the application and document events. I have already disabled all the third party VSTO installed here.

Answer (score 1):

Stop defining callback events with delegates in your addin. Create an `AdviseSink` with the `IConnectionPoint` interface. cleanup an RCWs with Marshal.RCO when you are done.

Here are some good example articles to read up on:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/04/11/excel-ole-embedding-errors-if-you-have-managed-add-in-sinking-application-events-in-excel-2/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcook/2008/10/30/iconnectionpoint-and-net-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-managed-event-sinks-part-1/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2008/10/28/better-eventing-support-in-clr-4-0-using-nopia-support/
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mshneer/2008/10/18/com-interop-handling-events-has-side-effects/

General knowledge reading:

- [RCW reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [PIA reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302338.aspx)
- [Office specific PIA readin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)